# Regarding Big-O Notation for "reversing the string" code

Tags: perl, big-o

I wrote a code to reverse a string but I want to calculate the big o notation for my code.
I guess it is O(m+n). please correct me if this is wrong.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Please enter you string \n";
chomp (my $string = <STDIN>);
print "Entered string is $string \n";
my @word = split(" ",$string);

my $eachword;
foreach $eachword(@word){
    my @each = split(//,$eachword);
    my $wordlength = scalar(@each);
    for (my $j=$wordlength-1; $j>=0; $j--) {
        print $each[$j];

    }
    print " ";
}
```

input:

```
hai how are you
```

o/p :

```
iah woh era uoy
```

Comment: `perl -lne '$, = " "; print map scalar reverse, split'`

Comment: What are the numbers m and n?

Comment: @choroba `perl -plwe's/\S+/reverse $&/ge'` I tried making a regex based one, but I lost interest too quick. :D

Comment: You should reconsider your variable names.  An array contains many things, so you should consider a plural name, e.g. @words.  Next, `for` will accomplish the same thing as `foreach`, and because for is shorter to type, use for.  As a result, most loops will look like this: `for my $word (@words)`.  Note how the $ variable is the singular of the @ variable.

Comment: @7stud : Hi thanks for you suggestions will follow the same in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what `m` and `n` are :) Normally `n` denotes the length of the whole input. In such case your algorithm uses `O(n)` time (and `O(n)` space - memory as well - at least I assume so, I am not very familiar with perl and its implementation of `split`).

"Proof" would follow the idea that your algorithm split input into `m <= n` words of lengths `l_1 + .. l_m = n` (without loss of generality let's ignore spaces). Each of word you reverse in `l_1` time (outputing each letter). This gives you final `O(n)` time as sum (+ initial linear split).

Answer (score 1):

Using the big o notation you don't care about constants but the complexity assuming values near infinity, so m+n or 2n are within o(n). Let n be your number of words and m be the maximum number of characters which you can assume as constant since n is your real scalability issue. So it's n + c(constant) = o(n). Further reading: [Big O notation](http://web.mit.edu/16.070/www/lecture/big_o.pdf).

Comment: @sodik:Thanks for your explanations.I assume 'm' is a time taken to process each word in the sentence (hai how are you) and 'n' is a time taken to process each word (hai => iah).

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. I assumed 2n > o(n)

Comment: Using the big o notation 2n comes down to o(n) because every constant is pointless getting close to infinity. There is also an example of this in the reading I attached: T(n) = 4n² - 2n + 2 = o(n²) [not 4n²].